# How to make a struct where one of the fields refers to another field

Tags: rust

I have the following problem: I have a have a data structure that is parsed from a buffer and contains some references into this buffer, so the parsing function looks something like

```
fn parse_bar<'a>(buf: &'a [u8]) -> Bar<'a>
```

So far, so good. However, to avoid certain lifetime issues I'd like to put the data structure and the underlying buffer into a struct as follows:

```
struct BarWithBuf<'a> {bar: Bar<'a>, buf: Box<[u8]>}
// not even sure if these lifetime annotations here make sense,
// but it won't compile unless I add some lifetime to Bar
```

However, now I don't know how to actually construct a `BarWithBuf` value.

```
fn make_bar_with_buf<'a>(buf: Box<[u8]>) -> BarWithBuf<'a> {
    let my_bar = parse_bar(&*buf);
    BarWithBuf {buf: buf, bar: my_bar}
}
```

doesn't work, since `buf` is moved in the construction of the BarWithBuf value, but we borrowed it for parsing.

I feel like it should be possible to do something along the lines of

```
fn make_bar_with_buf<'a>(buf: Box<[u8]>) -> BarWithBuf<'a> {

    let mut bwb = BarWithBuf {buf: buf};
    bwb.bar = parse_bar(&*bwb.buf);
    bwb
}
```

to avoid moving the buffer after parsing the `Bar`, but I can't do that because the whole `BarWithBuf` struct has to be initalised in one go.
Now I suspect that I could use `unsafe` code to partially construct the struct, but I'd rather not do that.
What would be the best way to solve this problem? Do I need unsafe code? If I do, would it be safe do to this here? Or am I completely on the wrong track here and there is a better way to tie a data structure and its underlying buffer together?

Comment: I never figured out if it is possible to have internal references to an other member of a struct without unsafe code. I can't see how the borrow checker could follow a borrow like this one...

Comment: This question is old enough that I don't want to close it as a duplicate, but most people visiting this should probably check out [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're right in that it's not possible to do this without unsafe code. I would consider the following two options:

1. Change the reference in `Bar` to an index. The contents of the box won't be protected by a borrow, so the index might become invalid if you're not careful. However, an index might convey the meaning of the reference in a clearer way.
2. Move `Box<[u8]>` into `Bar`, and add a function `buf() -> &[u8]` to the implementation of `Bar`; instead of references, store indices in `Bar`. Now `Bar` is the owner of the buffer, so it can control its modification and keep the indices valid (thereby avoiding the problem of option #1).
3. As per DK's suggestion below, store indices in `BarWithBuf` (or in a helper struct `BarInternal`) and add a function `fn bar(&self) -> Bar` to the implementation of `BarWithBuf`, which constructs a `Bar` on-the-fly.

Which of these options is the most appropriate one depends on the actual problem context. I agree that some form of "member-by-member construction" of structs would be immensely helpful in Rust.

Comment: I've considered the first options, but I don't particularly like it. I have trouble understanding your second suggestion, could you maybe elaborate on that?

Comment: @fjh I believe Adrian is suggesting that you wrap the `Box` in a type which has a method that returns a temporary `Bar`.  The idea is that you store a "portable" form of the `Bar` (like indices into the boxed data), and the method constructs a `Bar` on-demand, using the lifetime of `&self` to keep things safe.

Comment: @DK. Not quite, but I clarified option #2 and added your suggestion as option #3.

Comment: Thank you! I'll probably just bite the bullet and use `String` and `Vec` instead of referring to the buffer to sidestep this whole issue. Index-based solutions feel a bit hacky and wouldn't really work for me since some of the references into the buffer are `&str`, so I'd have to repeatedly verify the the utf encoding or use unsafe code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will work through a *little bit* of unsafe code. This approach requires that you are okay with putting the referred-to thing (here, your `[u8]`) on the heap, so it won't work for direct reference of a sibling field.

Let's start with a toy `Bar<'a>` implementation:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    refs: Vec<&'a [u8]>,
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    pub fn parse(src: &'a [u8]) -> Self {
        // placeholder for actually parsing goes here
        Self { refs: vec![src] }
    }
}
```

We'll make `BarWithBuf` that uses a `Bar<'static>`, as `'static` is the only lifetime with an an accessible name. The buffer we store things in can be anything that doesn't move the target data around on us. I'm going to go with a `Vec<u8>`, but `Box`, `Pin`, whatever will work fine.

```
struct BarWithBuf {
    buf: Vec<u8>,
    bar: Bar<'static>,
}
```

The implementation requires a tiny bit of unsafe code.

```
impl BarWithBuf {
    pub fn new(buf: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        // The `&'static [u8]` is inferred, but writing it here for demo
        let buf_slice: &'static [u8] = unsafe {
            // Going through a pointer is a "good" way to get around lifetime checks
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(&buf[0], buf.len())
        };
        let bar = Bar::parse(buf_slice);
        Self { buf, bar }
    }

    /// Access to Bar should always come through this function.
    pub fn bar(&self) -> &Bar {
        &self.bar
    }
}
```

The `BarWithBuf::bar` is an important function to re-associate the proper lifetimes to the references. Rust's [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) rules make the function equivalent to `pub fn bar<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Bar<'a>`, which turns out to be exactly what we want. The lifetime of the slices in `BarWithBuf::bar::refs` are tied to the lifetime of `BarWithBuf`.

**WARNING**: You have to be very careful with your implementation here. You cannot make `#[derive(Clone)]` for `BarWithBuf`, since the default clone implementation will clone `buf`, but the elements of `bar.refs` will still point to the original. It is only one line of `unsafe` code, but the safety is still off in the "safe" bits.

---

For larger bits of self-referencing structures, there's the [ouroboros](https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros) crate, which wraps up a lot of unsafe bits for you. The techniques are similar to the one I described above, but they live behind macros, which is a more pleasant experience if you find yourself making a number of self-references.