# Structs with slices pointing to data in themselves

Tags: rust

I have a struct

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    buf: [u8, ..64],
    slice: &'a [u8]
}
```

The slice is supposed to point into the `buf` field of the struct. Is there any way to construct such a struct? Something like:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new() -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo {
            buf: [0, ..64],
            slice: ???? /* I don't know what to write here */
    }
}
```

If I try to do something like the following, the borrow checker complains (correctly), since the slice will have a shorter lifetime than the struct.

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new() -> Foo<'a> {
        let buf = [0, ..64];
        Foo {
            buf: buf,
            slice: buf.slice_from(0)
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that for this simple case I could keep offsets and manually call the slice functions:

```
struct Foo {
    buf: [u8, ..64],
    slice_from: uint,
    slice_to: uint
}
```

However this question is just a simplification of a more general use case of a struct owning data and having references into the same data and I'm wondering if that is possible (in a safe way) in Rust.

Comment: I have asked a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092273/how-to-make-a-struct-where-one-of-the-fields-refers-to-another-field) and unfortunately it seems like there is no safe way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't do it safely, because in general such a structure is not movable. Pretend it is possible, and you can create such a structure:

```
let foo = Foo {
    buf: [0, ..64],
    slice: obtain_slice_somehow()
};
```

The `slice` field is now a slice of `buf` field, in particular, it contains a pointer to `buf`, which is currently located on the stack. Now put `foo` into a box and return it from the function:

```
return Box::new(foo);
```

`foo` value is now moved to heap, and the function exits, freeing its stack memory. However, `slice` pointer *is not adjusted* to point to heap, because it is impossible to do in general, and so it left dangling, violating memory safety.

Comment: I understand. However, what if buf was a Vec<u8>? Then the pointer would always be on the heap and wouldn't become invalid even if foo was moved.

Comment: I just realized that the vec can of course reallocate as it grows, causing the old pointer in the slice to become invalid. However, it seems to be possible to fool the borrow checker by doing something like that. I might add another question pertaining to that though.

Comment: @dnaq, I doubt that it is possible to fool the borrow checker :) If you're able to, it is most certainly a bug in rustc.

Comment: I was able to fool the borrow checker, the bug report is [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19537) and the associated reddit post is [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2oappt/fooling_the_borrow_checker_bug/).