# Wrapping an iterator plus adaptors in a custom type

Tags: rust, iterator, state, traits

I am using a library that provides an iterable type, once it has been set up. I would like to create a custom type that encapsulates this setup, to (a) emit the values I want, after adaptation, (b) make it reproducible and to (c) keep logic separate. I *think* I understand what I need to do, but I'm having trouble actually creating the type, which will have an `Iterator` implementation, as I don't see how to embed the necessary state into it to satisfy the compiler (particularly lifetimes and borrows).

Say I have:

```rust
struct MyItem<'a> {
    foo: &'a str
}

struct ItemCollection<'a> {
    state: &'a str
}

struct ItemCollectionIter<'a> {
    // What goes in here?
}
```

`IntoIterator` is implemented for `ItemCollection<'a>`, which sets up an `ItemCollectionIter<'a>` value. The `ItemCollectionIter<'a>` type must contain all the necessary state to be able to call `Iterator::next` against it. Something like this:

```rust
impl<'a> IntoIterator for ItemCollection<'a> {
    type Item = MyItem<'a>;
    type IntoIter = ItemCollectionIter<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        // <Set up library's iterator state here...>
        let library_iterator = some_library::Cursor::new();

        Self::IntoIter {
            // library_iterator and all its state goes in here, somehow
        }
    }
}
```

In the `into_iter` implementation, to construct `library_iterator`, I need to create other bits of state. If I create them in `into_iter`, they are local to `into_iter` and so their lifetime is shorter than `library_iterator`. I can easily include the local state in the `ItemCollectionIter` type, but then how do I construct `library_iterator` such that it depends on these longer-lived values?

(Follow-Up: I don't actually want to store `library_iterator` as the state to iterate over. I want to store the iterator with a bunch of adaptors applied: `library_iterator.adaptor(whatever).another_adaptor(foo).etc(bar)`. The type of this is whatever the type of the final adaptor happens to be. I believe, however, that exacerbates the problem of storing dependent state.)

---

**Alternative** It's highly possible that my understanding is off, or there's an easier approach. What follows is therefore the "zero assumption" version of my question...

I have a library that, after setting up its state, produces an iterator, to which I apply a handful of adaptors to get output in the shape I want. Something like this:

```rust
// <Set up library's iterator state here...>
let iterator = some_library::Cursor::new();

for val in iterator.search(/* library state */).flat_map(something).map(another_thing) {
    println!("{val:?}");
}
```

I want to encapsulate this -- for the reasons stated above -- so I can ultimately write something like:

```rust
let iterator = ItemCollection { state: /* whatever */ };

for val in iterator {
    println!("{val:?}");
}
```

I *believe* the top half of my question is how one achieves this, in a general sense. That said, given I already have an iterator, maybe there's a simpler way of writing a "wrapper type" for that, rather than the first-principles approach.

Comment: [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092273/how-to-make-a-struct-where-one-of-the-fields-refers-to-another-field) describes a similar problem, fixing it with unsafe Rust or using a library ([ouroboros](https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros))... I can try this, but I can't help but feeling that I'm making it harder than needs be; that I'm doing something suboptimally.

Comment: What you're describing is a self-referential struct, which is known to be hard to impossible to implement safely. I'd recommend you to try `ourobors`.

Comment: Your "zero-assumption" question can be solved with simply: `let iterator = Cursor::new().search (todo!()).flat_map (todo!()).map (todo!()); for val in iterator { todo!(); }`. Unfortunately the type of `iterator` can't be named, so you will need to box it if you want to use it somewhere type inference and `impl Iterator` can't be used.